# How do I set up jumbotron so that I can control it through a panel?

Tags: 7, panels, bootstrap-theme

I am using the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Panels Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_bootstrap_layouts) modules, and I would like to have a Jumbotron block in a couple of pages.

How do I set it up so that I can control it through a panel, like shown in [Drupal Restaurant: Add Jumbotron Page Banner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vndRpEYVmRQ)?

Answer (score 0):

So I just recently created a jumbotron functionality for a site I worked on. I used panels, bootstrap and a custom node type to achieve this and it worked pretty well.

The video from the link you provided looks like they did something similar except they have some enhancements to panels and the node creation page that may be from a custom module or another module I am not familiar with.

What you will want to do is to create a new content type called Jumbotron and add the fields you want. You could also install the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module to help with getting grouped fields together.

You will need to create a new template file for that node view but I am going to assume you know how to do that to get your fields to render correctly and that you know how to use a hook_preprocess_node function as needed as well.

You can then create as many jumbotrons you want the normal way of creating nodes, and using panels, you can add the same jumbotron entity to as many pages as you want using the "Add Existing Node" option.

To get the EXACT functionality from your link I don't know if there is a  list of contrib modules to get you that without doing anything custom.

Hope that helps,